# React native BUILD FAILED in 32m 5s error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

[React native BUILD FAILED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSfTO.png)

FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
> ==============================================================================

### 3: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
> ==============================================================================

BUILD FAILED in 32m 5s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.